# How to generate update.rdf with jpm

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

Rather than [`cfx`'s `--updateurl` command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx#updateURL_and_updateLink), with `jpm`, we can simply [place the `updateURL` in `package.json`](https://github.com/mozilla/jpm/issues/180). This URL points to a file called `update.rdf`, which tells self-hosted addons where to look for updates.

With `cfx`, that `update.rdf` file could be generated with the `--updatelink`, but that option [has been removed from `jpm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx_to_jpm#Permanently_removed_options). I can't figure out how to generate `update.rdf` using `jpm`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made [issue 288](https://github.com/mozilla/jpm/issues/288) for this, in the meantime you will need to follow these instructions to learn how to build the update.rdf yourself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Update_RDF_Format

Comment: Yeah, I just modified an update.rdf file I had created before using that link. Thanks for the answer.